# Warning on local variable on operator overload, following a tutorial, don't know what to do

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I was reading a document on operator overloading: http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html however when I run the code below (in an actual context) I always get a warning on how result is a local variable. And it makes sense that I shouldn't be returning a local variable, but it seems to work fine. Is there a way to eliminate the warning with code like the following:

```
const Matrix & Matrix::operator+(const Matrix &other) const
{
  Matrix result(*this);
  result += other;
  return result;
}
```

The example on caltech's website like this, is on the bottom of the [link](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html)

Comment: Just return it by value. By the way, the more canonical form of this is a free function: `Matrix operator+(Matrix lhs, const Matrix &rhs) {return lhs += rhs;}`

Comment: Oh woops, that makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the warning, you need to return the `Matrix` by value.

You should also *ideally* define it as a free function since semantically it should not need to modify the object it is called on.

Answer (score 1):

`operator+()` should not return a reference type as it is a new (locally declared) instance that holds the result of the operation.

```
Matrix operator+(Matrix lhs, const Matrix &rhs)
{
  return lhs += rhs;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you try to return **reference** to object that will be destroyed outside your function. You must return **object** (not reference to object).

Comment: To add to this answer, returning a reference to a local variable that will not be alive in the calling scope is called a dangling reference.